# Implementing Wait and Notify

Tags: java, wait, notify, kdb

I'm trying to write a program that checks on the health of a database. One of the elements of the elements of the program is supposed to be that the program queries a database and then waits 5 minutes using wait. If there is no response it notifies and sends out some emails. My connection to the database/sending out emails all works, but i'm having trouble implementing wait and notify.
I read the api and its easy to understand in a simple program, but i'm really confused as to how to implement it in this case with all the additional complications because of errors where I can't call something dynamic from a static method.

I've been reading through lots of threads with wait and notify, but haven't figured out how do to it correctly in my program. If anyone could give me a few tips it would be a huge help. Thanks!

```
import com.fmr.ipgt.email.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

class MyResource {
synchronized void qQuery() throws Exception {
    String query = ".z.k"; // The query that is used to query q; this can be changed here.
    int version = 0;
    c qConn = null;
    qConn = new c(Main.host,Main.port); // Connect to the q database
      while (Main.healthy) {
          Object o = qConn.k(query); // Query q
          version = c.t(o);
          if(!(version==0)) {
              break; // End the process if the database responds
          }
          }
  }
  synchronized void start() throws Exception {
    Main.setHealth(false);
    Main.sendMessages();
  }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
  MyResource myResource;

  MyThread(String name, MyResource so) {
    myResource = so;
    new Thread(this, name).start();
  }

  public void run() {

    try {
      myResource.qQuery(); // Begin a method to query q.
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public class Main {

private static String[] recipients;
private static String subject = "Database Failure";
private static String message = "The database has failed or is in a hung state";
private static String from;
static String host;
static int port;
private static String emails;
private static int minutes;
static boolean healthy = true;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // Import information from the configuration file
      SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
      File xmlFile = new File("/export/home/jflt/file.xml"); // Note: The directory for the configuration file may need to be changed

      try {

        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren("parameters");
           Element node = (Element) list.get(0);

          host = node.getChildText("host");
           port = Integer.parseInt(node.getChildText("port"));
           emails = node.getChildText("emails");
           String delims = "[ ]+";
           recipients = emails.split(delims); // parse email list
           minutes = Integer.parseInt(node.getChildText("time"));
           from = node.getChildText("from");

      } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
      } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
      }
    MyResource unhealthy = new MyResource();
    new MyThread("MyThread", unhealthy);  // Create new Thread
    new MyThread("WaitThread", unhealthy);
    while(healthy) {
    Thread.sleep(minutes*60000); // The wrong thread is sleeping here. The main method should probably be a different thread instead which will then need to wait and the second thread will notify.
    }
    unhealthy.start(); // The database has not responded for the given time. Report that it is unhealthy.
  }
  public static void setHealth(boolean health){
      System.out.println("database unhealthy");
    healthy  = health;  
  }

  public static void sendMessages() throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("sending emails");
      FCAPMailSender.postMail(recipients,subject,message,from);
  }
  }
```

Comment: This is too much code. Boil the problem down to the basics before posting. Make an SSCCE.

Comment: hmm well i suppose i could delete the code because none of it is really relevant to what i'm asking. i'm just trying to figure out how to do wait and notify where thread 2 starts a query, thread 1 waits 5 minutes, if thread 2 returns a result it notifies, if not, thread 1 does a different task.             The problem for me is that in all the wait and notify examples the threads use one run method and do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a task with an `ExecutorService` that sends email. When you get a response, cancel the task. If it's been more than 5 minutes, the mail has already been sent by the executor thread, and cancellation is a no-op. Otherwise, the email is aborted.

---

This isn't even a `wait()`/`notify()` problem; there's no data passing between threads. Here's a low level equivalent to the `ExecutorService` solution.

```
void test() {
  Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try { Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)); } 
      catch(InterruptedException abort) { return; }
      email();
    }
  }
  t.start();
  query();
  t.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: hmm this seems like a pretty good idea. i would like to use wait and notify though because my manager specifically said that he wanted wait and notify.   Also, I think what i'm confused by is that in examples the threads always do the same thing, like they both countdown, but I need the threads to do two very different things with different methods controlling them.

Answer (score 0):

If wait and notify is to be used, i will advice you to use the **Lock Interface** and **Reentrant Lock Class** from `java.util.concurrent package...`